# How to graphically solve this inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Could anybody show me how to solve this ?

$$|y| \leq |x-1|$$

Comment: Do you know that $|a|<b\iff -b<a<b$?

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how to start that exercise

Comment: If it was me, I'd cheat: solve algebraically, then graph it.

Answer (score 1):

We can equivalently rewrite this as $$-|x-1|\le y\le |x-1|,$$ so we're looking to shade the area between (and including) the graphs of $y=|x-1|$ and $y=-|x-1|.$

Comment: Thank you, i'll try with that.

Comment: So, now i have y=x-1 and y=-x+1, what should i do now ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have $y=x-1$ and $y=-x+1$"? You should be shading between the graphs $y=|x-1|$ and $y=-|x-1|$.

Answer (score 0):

$y=|x-1|$:
[image: graph 1]

$y=-|x-1|$:
[image: graph 2]

Now we draw both graphs:
[image: graph mix]

... and fill area between upper lines ($y=|x-1|$) and lower lines ($y=-|x-1|$):

$-|x-1| \le y \le |x-1|$:
[image: graph 3]

For each point $(x,y)$ of gray region
upper $y$-bound is $|x-1|$, and lower $y$-bound is $-|x-1|$.

As example: point $(3,1)$ belongs to gray region. 
$x=3$, $y=1$.
$y_{\rm upper} = |x-1|=2$, $y_{\rm lower}=-|x-1|=-2$.
And, of course, $y_{\rm lower}\leqslant y \leqslant y_{\rm upper}$.